# PHP Downloads Some Empty Files and Some Normally

Tags: php

I have this code to download a Zip file from the server:

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo($_GET['a']);
$file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
$file_path  = 'temp/' . $file_name;

if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    $size = filesize($file_path);

    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-length: $size");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // read the file from disk
    readfile($file_path);
}

else
    echo 'File does not exists';
?>
```

The files are stored in a `/temp` folder and the curious thing is that if I download a `TXT` file, it downlads OK, but if the file is a `ZIP` file then it downloads an empty file. Even if I change the extension of the `ZIP` file to `TXT` it still downloads empty, but any other file download just fine. What could be causing this behavior?

In fact, it downloads any other file but the `ZIP` files in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that PHP is not reading the `ZIP` files generated by the Java App that produces them. But, any other `ZIP` file is being read.

As I am using Java to create the `ZIP` files, I had to replace the method by this one posted here (https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/). It now works normally.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the file size, not the extension.  Look in your php.ini file and see what these values are set to.  If your file is larger than these, this would explain it.

```
post_max_size=5M
upload_max_filesize=5M
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
```

instead of

```
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
```

Comment: I just did and it downloads `TXT`, `JAR` files and any other files, but the `ZIP` files are all empty.